# RecyclerView Scrolling slows after returning from activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am coding a news/article app with **Firebase Firestore**. And, I use RecyclerView to list items(imageview with constant high, textview) that have constant heights. This process is done on FragmentNews, and when I click the item to see detail, there is an intent to another activity. After returning that activity (click Back), recyclerview scrolling **slows**. I read old answers, but they could not help me,
here is my code Recyclerview adapter code

```
package com.fabrika.gunes;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearSnapHelper;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyRecMultiAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements MySubMultiRecListAdapter.ItemClickListenerSub{

    private Context context;
    public static ArrayList<MakalaModel> list;
    static ItemClickListener mClickListener;
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    String isWifiEnabled = "0", isOnlyWifi = "0";

    public MyRecMultiAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MakalaModel> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;

        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        isWifiEnabled = preferences.getString("wifi_enabled", "0");
        isOnlyWifi = preferences.getString("wifi_only", "0");
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        if(viewType==0){
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list_makala_vertical, parent, false);
            NormMakalaHolder postHolder = new NormMakalaHolder(view);
            return postHolder;
        }
        else if(viewType==1){
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.makala_rec_row, parent, false);
            RecMakalaHolder authorHolder = new RecMakalaHolder(view);
            return authorHolder;
        }
        return null;

    }

    public static ArrayList<MakalaModel> getList(){
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if(getItemViewType(position)==0){
            MakalaModel postModel = list.get(position);
            NormMakalaHolder postHolder = (NormMakalaHolder) holder;
            postHolder.t_category.setText(postModel.getArticle_author());
            String firstWord = postModel.getArticle_title();
            String secondWord = postModel.getArticle_body().substring(0,150)+"...";
            postHolder.t_view.setText(""+postModel.getArticle_view_number());

// Create a new spannable with the two strings
            Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(firstWord+ ". " +secondWord);
// Set the custom typeface to span over a section of the spannable object
            Typeface typeface1 = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.nunitosans_extra_bold);
            Typeface typeface2 = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.nunitosans_light);
            spannable.setSpan( new CustomTypefaceSpan("sans-serif", typeface1), 0, firstWord.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            spannable.setSpan( new CustomTypefaceSpan("sans-serif", typeface2), firstWord.length(), firstWord.length() + secondWord.length()+2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

// Set the text of a textView with the spannable object
            postHolder.t_title.setText( spannable );

            String url = list.get(position).getArticle_img_url();
            if(isOnlyWifi.equals("1") && isWifiEnabled.equals("0")){
                url = "";
            }

            try {
                Glide
                        .with(context)
                        .load(new URL(url))
                        .centerCrop()
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.mini_map)
                        .into(postHolder.i_image);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        else{
            ArrayList<MakalaModel> listMakala = list.get(position).getListMakalaModel();
            MySubMultiRecListAdapter adapter = new MySubMultiRecListAdapter(context, listMakala);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
            ((RecMakalaHolder) holder).recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            ((RecMakalaHolder) holder).recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
//            LinearSnapHelper linearSnapHelper = new SnapHelperOneByOne();
//            linearSnapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(((RecMakalaHolder) holder).recyclerView);
            adapter.setClickListenerSub(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return list.get(position).getViewType();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position, ArrayList<MakalaModel> list) {
        
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityMakala.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", list.get(position).getMakala_id());
        intent.putExtra("type", "Articles");
        intent.putExtra("category", list.get(position).getArticle_category());
        intent.putExtra("date", list.get(position).getArticle_date());
        intent.putExtra("title", list.get(position).getArticle_title());
        intent.putExtra("author", list.get(position).getArticle_author());
        intent.putExtra("body", list.get(position).getArticle_body());
        intent.putExtra("img_url", list.get(position).getArticle_img_url());
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    public class RecMakalaHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        RecyclerView recyclerView;

        public RecMakalaHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            recyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (MyRecMultiAdapter.mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition(), MyRecMultiAdapter.getList());
        }
    }

    public class NormMakalaHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        TextView t_category, t_title, t_view;
        ImageView i_image;

        public NormMakalaHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            t_category = itemView.findViewById(R.id.t_category);
            t_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.t_title);
            i_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.i_image);
            t_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.t_view);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (MyRecMultiAdapter.mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition(), MyRecMultiAdapter.getList());
        }
    }

    // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position, ArrayList<MakalaModel> list);
    }

    // allows clicks events to be caught
    public void setClickListenerSub(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

}
```

and, here is my FragmentNews code

```
package com.fabrika.gunes;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.content.IntentCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class FragmentMakala extends Fragment implements MyRecMultiAdapter.ItemClickListener{

    View view;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    public static ArrayList<MakalaModel> makalaObjects;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    MainActivity activity;
    MyRecMultiAdapter adapter;
    FloatingActionButton buttonInsertArticle;
    HashMap<String, Boolean> likedArticles;
    FirebaseFirestore db;
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    String[] likedArray;

    long article_number = 0;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_makala, container, false);

        prepareMe();

        getMakala();

        buttonInsertArticle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // for admin
//                insertEmptyArticle();
            }
        });



        return view;
    }

    private void insertEmptyArticle() {

        // Create a new user with a first and last name
        Map<String, Object> article = new HashMap<>();
        article.put("article_author", "Serdaryň pikirleri");
        article.put("article_body", "");
        article.put("article_category", "durmuş");
        article.put("article_date", "01.05.2021");
        article.put("article_dislike_number", 0);
        article.put("article_img_url", "");
        article.put("article_like_number", 0);
        article.put("article_title", "");
        article.put("article_valid", true);
        article.put("article_view_number", 0);

// Add a new document with a generated ID
        db.collection("Articles")
                .document(""+article_number)
                .set(article);

        article_number++;

        Map<String, Object> article_num = new HashMap<>();
        article_num.put("article_number", article_number);


        db.collection("Articles")
                .document("0")
                .set(article_num);
    }

    private void prepareMe() {



//        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).updateStatusBarColor("#ffffff");

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);//Add this sentence to the menu
        toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
        toolbar.setTitle("Iň täze makalalar");
        toolbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "refresh", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                getMakala();
            }
        });
        buttonInsertArticle = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonInsertNewArticle);
        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        makalaObjects = new ArrayList<>();
        isWifiEnabled();

        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        adapter = new MyRecMultiAdapter(view.getContext(), makalaObjects);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter.setClickListenerSub(this);

        likedArticles = new HashMap<>();
        String ids = preferences.getString("liked_articles","");
        likedArray = ids.split(" ");

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(2);
        recyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        recyclerView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
//        adapter.setHasStableIds(true);

    }

    public void initScrollView(){
        if(makalaObjects.size()>3){

            ArrayList<MakalaModel> scrollList = new ArrayList<>();

            String ids = preferences.getString("liked_articles","");
            likedArray = ids.split(" ");
            for(int i=likedArray.length-1;i>=0;i--){
                for(int j=makalaObjects.size()-1;j>=0;j--){
                    if(likedArray[i].equals(makalaObjects.get(j).getMakala_id())){
                        scrollList.add(makalaObjects.get(j));
                    }
                }
            }
            MakalaModel m = new MakalaModel();
            m.setListMakalaModel(scrollList);
            m.setViewType(1);
            makalaObjects.set(3,m);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position, ArrayList<MakalaModel> list) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), ActivityMakala.class);
        intent.putExtra("type", "Articles");
        intent.putExtra("position", position);
        intent.putExtra("id", makalaObjects.get(position).getMakala_id());
        intent.putExtra("category", makalaObjects.get(position).getArticle_category());
        intent.putExtra("date", makalaObjects.get(position).getArticle_date());
        intent.putExtra("title", makalaObjects.get(position).getArticle_title());
        intent.putExtra("author", makalaObjects.get(position).getArticle_author());
        intent.putExtra("body", makalaObjects.get(position).getArticle_body());
        intent.putExtra("img_url", makalaObjects.get(position).getArticle_img_url());
//        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void getMakala() {

        makalaObjects.clear();
//        adapter = null;
//        activity.llprogress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        db.collection("Articles").get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        if(!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()){

                            List<DocumentSnapshot> list = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();

                            for(DocumentSnapshot d : list){
                                MakalaModel makalaModel = d.toObject(MakalaModel.class);
                                makalaModel.setMakala_id(d.getId());
                                makalaModel.setViewType(0);

                                if(!makalaModel.getMakala_id().equals("0"))
                                    makalaObjects.add(makalaModel);
                                else{
                                    article_number = makalaModel.getArticle_number();
                                }
                            }

//                            Collections.reverse(makalaObjects);

                            makalaObjects.sort((schedule1, schedule2)->{
                                int returnValue = 0;
                                if(Integer.parseInt(schedule1.getMakala_id()) > Integer.parseInt(schedule2.getMakala_id())) return -1;
                                else if(Integer.parseInt(schedule1.getMakala_id()) < Integer.parseInt(schedule2.getMakala_id()))    return 1;
                                return returnValue;
                            });

                            ArrayList<MakalaModel> scrollList = new ArrayList<>();

                            for(int i=likedArray.length-1;i>=0;i--){
                                for(int j=makalaObjects.size()-1;j>=0;j--){
                                    if(likedArray[i].equals(makalaObjects.get(j).getMakala_id())){
                                        scrollList.add(makalaObjects.get(j));
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            MakalaModel m = new MakalaModel();
                            m.setListMakalaModel(scrollList);
                            m.setViewType(1);
                            makalaObjects.add(3,m);

                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//                            adapter = new MyRecMultiAdapter(activity.getApplicationContext(), makalaObjects);
//                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                            activity.llprogress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                activity.llprogress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }});
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        isWifiEnabled();
        initScrollView();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public boolean isWifiEnabled(){
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) activity.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo wifiNetwork = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

        if (wifiNetwork != null && wifiNetwork.isConnected()) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString("wifi_enabled", "1");
            editor.commit();
            return true;
        }
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("wifi_enabled", "0");
        editor.commit();
        return false;
    }
}
```

my item_list_makala_vertical.xml code (list item of recyclerview)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:paddingVertical="5dp"
    android:paddingHorizontal="15dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t_category"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="WHAT TO COOK"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunitosans_black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:fontFamily="@font/verdana"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/t_category"
        android:text="New Recipes for Your Rotation Add vegan tantanment and roasted rhubarb cobbler to your weekend cooking plans."/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/i_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:src="@drawable/mini_map"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/t_title"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/r_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/i_image">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="27.04.2021"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/nunitosans_light"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:alpha="0.6"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/t_view"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_view"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="24"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/nunitosans_bold"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/colorBlack"
        android:layout_below="@+id/r_bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for your help...

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **600 (six hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code when loading image with gilde :

```
            Glide.with(context).load(new URL(url))
                    .thumbnail(0.5f)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(postHolder.i_image);
```

is better paging your news data.

Comment: your welcome! if paging data it can better!